# Universal app difference between page and usercontrol, and how to create static regions

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism, win-universal-app, windows-10

I started to play with universal apps yesterday, and there is few things which confuse me. In WPF we have window or usercontrol, and these are clear to me, however in universal app there is a page and usercontrol as well, and I'm confused when to actually use page over usercontrol (because some stuff like nivigation in prism looks for pages not for usercontrols). I also cannot find how to switch usercontrols/pages, without the need to navigate the entire thing. So let’s say I have a header and a footer section, I want them to be consistant as the dont change. In WPF I use prism, to create regions, and I only navigate inside the regions, it does not look like there is a way to do it in Universal app, or is there? I don't want to repeat the same stuff on all pages/usercontrols etc. Any advices please, I tried to look online but not much information about achieving this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In WPF we have window or usercontrol, and these are clear to me,
>   however in universal app there is a page and usercontrol as well

The WPF XAML Framework and UWP XAML Framework have some different design.

**WPF:**

```
public class Window : ContentControl, IWindowService
```

**UWP:**

```
public class Frame : ContentControl, IFrame, INavigate, IFrame2, IFrame3
public class Page : UserControl, IPage, IPageOverrides
```

**Frame vs. Window**

WPF is a Windows desktop application, so it uses the Window as the root element.
UWP introduced a build-in navigation model, the page is in a frame and the frame has the ability to navigate between pages.

> So let’s say I have a header and a footer section, I want them to be consistant as the dont change.

You can put the navigable content in a sub-frame.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Header</TextBlock>
        <Frame x:Name="pages">
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
        </Frame>
        <TextBlock>Footer</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: My only concern regarding adding Frames within Pages (I assume that is what you suggest) is that you have multiple navigation backstacks to maintain and that makes it more difficult to restore state after suspension.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll try it hopefully tonight, and if it works then I accept the answer.

Comment: @Corcus should I be worried about that suspension state? I only just started to work with it, in free time, so don't have much experience at all.

Comment: This is a good video to familiarize yourself with the [app lifecycle](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-RTM/Application-Lifecycle) . as Jeffrey said the frame is used to navigate between pages. So it has a navigation backstack which details the users navigation. This backstack has to be saved when the app is suspended and restored when it is restarted after termination in order to provide a good user experience. When you have multiple frames this can be a little more complicated :)

Comment: It works with pages, navigating to usercontrol throws null exception even thought I could not find what the null was. Is there a way to tell prism to navigate only within these sub frames? because when I used prism navigation service, does not matter what I do, it changes the entire page.

Comment: @adminSoftDK, in UWP, the Prism use FrameNavigationService for navigation by default, and it also use Frame.Navigate to navigate between pages internally. And the Frame.Navigate causes the Frame to load content represented by the specified Page. So a normal usercontrol will not work.